# Creating an implimentation of netstat for Solaris in Python2.6+

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, solaris, computer-forensics

I am writing a collection script in python to grab forensic artifacts from various *nix hosts using Python 2 scripts, however I am running into some issues writing netstat collection for Solaris.

There are a few limitations to how I am to achieve this. I cannot use the ELF binaries (except Python) on the computer (as they are often manipulated when *nix machines are attacked), I cannot import external libraries (as this will not run on computers which I administer), and it must be written in Python 2 for backwards compatibility reasons.

All this being said, I am using the netstat.c document by Illumos (an open source Solaris implementation) as my base, and essentially trying to reverse engineer this and rewrite it in Python 2.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/52916131/

What I've figured out so far is, the script opens '/dev/arp' and '/dev/kstat' to ensure there are return values.

```py
import os
sd = os.open('/dev/arp', os.O_RDWR)
kc = os.open('/dev/kstat', os.O_RDWR)
```

After this has been done, the 'sd' value is used to collect network statistics with the mibget() method.

And here's the rub. To collect the netstat information, Solaris is querying `sd` with the syscall `getmsg`, however it is using a datastructure I am unfamiliar with.

```c
getcode = getmsg(sd, &ctlbuf, (struct strbuf *)0, &flags);
```

I have no idea how to rebuild this in Python 2, do any of you fine people have any ideas of where I can go from here? Am I interpreting this wrong?

I understand the `psutil` implementation of netstat works on Solaris, so there must be a means to accomplish this.

Thank you all for your help.

Edit:

This appears to be the relevant section of `truss netstat`:

```c
open("/etc/default/inet_type", O_RDONLY)        Err#2 ENOENT
open("/dev/arp", O_RDWR)                        = 3
ioctl(3, I_PUSH, "tcp")                         = 0
ioctl(3, I_PUSH, "udp")                         = 0
ioctl(3, I_PUSH, "icmp")                        = 0
putmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0)            = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
getmsg(3, 0x00000000, 0x08047E48, 0x08047E5C)   = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
getmsg(3, 0x00000000, 0x08047E48, 0x08047E5C)   = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
getmsg(3, 0x00000000, 0x08047E48, 0x08047E5C)   = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
getmsg(3, 0x00000000, 0x08047E48, 0x08047E5C)   = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
getmsg(3, 0x00000000, 0x08047E48, 0x08047E5C)   = 0
getmsg(3, 0x08047E3C, 0x00000000, 0x08047E5C)   = 2
brk(0x080736E0)                                 = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getmsg()` and `struct strbuf` are [specified by POSIX, albeit marked as obsolescent in POSIX 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getmsg.html):

> **NAME**
>
> getmsg, getpmsg - receive next message from a STREAMS file (STREAMS)
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> [OB XSR] [Option Start] #include <stropts.h>
>
> int getmsg(int fildes, struct strbuf *restrict ctlptr,
>        struct strbuf *restrict dataptr, int *restrict flagsp);
> int getpmsg(int fildes, struct strbuf *restrict ctlptr,
>        struct strbuf *restrict dataptr, int *restrict bandp,
>        int *restrict flagsp); [Option End]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `getmsg()` function shall retrieve the contents of a message
>   located at the head of the STREAM head read queue associated with a
>   STREAMS file and place the contents into one or more buffers. The
>   message contains either a data part, a control part, or both. The data
>   and control parts of the message shall be placed into separate
>   buffers, as described below. The semantics of each part are defined by
>   the originator of the message.
>
> ...

I'm not aware of any Python bindings for STREAMS on Solaris.

[STREAMS functionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS) was never implemented on Linux.

Comment: Of course Solaris would use a protocol literally nobody else uses and is far past deprecated, unfortunately I don't know if this puts me any closer to solving the problem, as it appears I need to figure out whatever this arbitrary buffer is that they have set. Thank you!